# Save drawn polygon in googlemaps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hello guys i try to save a drawn polygon from a google map api , and i don't know how.I want to save the polygon(coordinates, or path and send them in as a form .This is what i have until now, i tried to read the documentation but i can't understand so much.

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 46.435812, lng: 27.639917},
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: 'hybrid'});

       var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
           drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
           drawingControl: true,
           drawingControlOptions: {
               position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
               drawingModes: ['polygon']
           },
       });

       drawingManager.setMap(map);
    };
</script>
```

Edit:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBR0YEEOUbWC8qYTig79dMHfOzXR44wX5w&libraries=geometry,drawing&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving coordinates and data from Google maps in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077286/saving-coordinates-and-data-from-google-maps-in-a-database)

Comment: what you posted is helping me but i dont need a rectangle i need a polygon.Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

For a polygon, do the same thing as is done in the similar question: [Saving coordinates and data from Google maps in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077286/saving-coordinates-and-data-from-google-maps-in-a-database), just use the appropriate event for a polygon (`polygoncomplete`) and process through the path, adding all the coordinates to your appropriate form field:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
  var coordStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    coordStr += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + ";";
    console.log(coordStr);
    document.getElementById('coords').value = coordStr;
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/62s4csq8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 46.435812,
      lng: 27.639917
    },
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: ['polygon']
    },
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    var coordStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      coordStr += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + ";";
    }
    document.getElementById('coords').value = coordStr;
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="coords" style="width:600px" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: it's ok "google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);" should be in the initMap.Now it's working

Comment: No, that shouldn't be in the `initMap` function.  If you have a `callback=initMap` in the include of the Google Maps Javascript API (which asynchronously calls `initMap` when the API finishes loading), then you don't need that line.

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)